# Cant Insert Data into Database Using Ajax - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, database

Im trying insert data into database when user sumbit form , but still no luck

I checked Console in Browser there is no error.

i debugged step by step My JsonResult and i can see Model Contains data and ModelState its true , but

When i debug my JsonResult, I can see Id Contains 0 (maybe Id is 0 cause the problem?!) and after i saw this i make if/else statement both in my Controller and in my Ajax , but still not working.

I also stored Id in a ViewBag.ID in my Json Result and than in View i make input field type hidden and stored the ViewBag.ID as value in input field.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?!

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ProcessRequestRMA(RMA_History model)
{

    ViewBag.ID = model.Id;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (ViewBag.ID == 0)
        {
            db.RMA_History.Add(new RMA_History
            {
                Id = ViewBag.ID,
                Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn,
                Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer

            });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


    }



    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

AJAX:

```
<form>

 <input name="Ordrenummer"  type="text" id="Ordrenummer" >

 <input name="Kundenavn"  type="text" id="Kundenavn" >

 <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="@ViewBag.ID" />

 <button id="btn" type="submit">Send</button>

 </form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return myfunction();
        });


        function myfunction() {

            var model = {

                Kundenavn: $("#Kundenavn").val(),
                Ordrenummer: $("#Ordrenummer").val(),
                Id: $("#Id").val()

            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Account/ProcessRequestRMA",
                dataType: 'json',

                data: {

                    Kundenavn: model.Kundenavn,
                    Ordrenummer: model.Ordrenummer,
                    Id: model.Id
                },

                beforeSend: function (status) {
                    if (model.Id == 0) {
                        status.Id = model.Id
                        status.Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn;
                        status.Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer;

                        console.log("Send");

                    }

                    else {
                        alert("Something Wrong");
                    }
                },
                success: function (run) {

                    if (run) {

                        console.log("Send success");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Something wrong in success");
                    }

                },

                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
            });
        }


    });
</script>
```

Model:

```
public class RMA_History
    {
public int Id { get; set; }  
public string Kundenummer { get; set; }
public string Ordrenummer { get; set; }

//Table & Column Mappings 
//Stuff here

//Key
HasKey(t => t.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (ViewBag.ID == 0)
{
    db.RMA_History.Add(new RMA_History
    {
        //here is your problem... typically you don't need to specify the id
        //after you save changes, the id will come back to you and then you 
        //can store it in the viewbag
        Id = ViewBag.ID,
        //other stuff
    }
 }
```

You are trying to save the record with an id of 0.  I'm assuming that in your database this is an auto increment column.

Try something like this instead:

```
var RMA = new RMA_History
{
    Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn,
    Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer
}

db.RMA_History.Add(RMA);
db.savechanges();
model.Id = RMA.Id;

return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thanks it helped :)